# Backport of `.merge()` for Angular 1.3.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, merge

Angular 1.4 (which is not stable yet) has a function that I'm interested in: [`.merge()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/docs/api/ng/function/angular.merge).

As I don't want to use an unstable library, I'm looking for a substitution of that method for Angular 1.3.x. Is there any "backports" library I could include in my project that will mimic Angular's `.merge()`?

Comment: @Satpal Can you extend that a little bit further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at the actual code, it's very well documented and you should be able to mimic it for yourself https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js:

Line 459

Merge function:

```
function merge(dst) {
    return baseExtend(dst, slice.call(arguments, 1), true);
}
```

Which uses the baseExtend function

```
function baseExtend(dst, objs, deep) {
    var h = dst.$$hashKey;

    for (var i = 0, ii = objs.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var obj = objs[i];
        if (!isObject(obj) && !isFunction(obj)) continue;
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var j = 0, jj = keys.length; j < jj; j++) {
            var key = keys[j];
            var src = obj[key];

            if (deep && isObject(src)) {
                if (!isObject(dst[key])) dst[key] = isArray(src) ? [] : {};
                baseExtend(dst[key], [src], true);
            } else {
                dst[key] = src;
            }
        }
    }

    setHashKey(dst, h);
    return dst;
}
```

Which uses

```
function setHashKey(obj, h) {
    if (h) {
        obj.$$hashKey = h;
    } else {
        delete obj.$$hashKey;
    }
}
```

Swap out the missing functions in baseExtend with angular versions (i.e. angular.isObject for isObject etc..)

Comment: I thought about that, but I had troubles with `slice.call`, which I'm not really sure what/where is defined. Any idea about that one?

Comment: Did you search through the file at all? Line 244: slice = [].slice,